# How to check which user is in which group to avoid dubbles

Tags: permissions

I have to manage accesses in a SharePoint site for more than 100 users with different access rights.

To manage it in the easiest way, I would like to check for a particular user in which group he is but I wasn't able to find out how to proceed in SharePoint?

Can someone explain to me how I could proceed?

Comment: what's your SharePoint version?

Comment: Are you looking for a code or no-code solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can verify each user individually if you go to Site Settings, and under the group "Users and Permissions" select "Site permissions."  From that screen, in the Ribbon there is a button called "Check Permissions" which will allow you to enter a user and it will display everywhere they have permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Using PowerShell you can check:

```
if ((Get-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell" -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) -eq $null) {
    Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
}

$web = get-spweb "http://yourSite"
$groups = $web.SiteGroups
$User = $groups["Your Group"].Users | where {$_.UserLogin -eq "domain\jdoe"}

if(!$User)
{
    Write-Host "user does NOT have access"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "user has access"
}
```

**Also**, you can't add a user to the same group twice. You can try, but the user will not appear in the group twice.